# Java Socket Sending Data

Tags: java, sockets

I have created two classes one server and client, I send data via the socket input and output stream however cant send multiple messages?

Server:

```
public class SOK_1_SERVER {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        SOK_1_SERVER Sever = new SOK_1_SERVER();
        Sever.run();
    }

    private void run() throws Exception {
        ServerSocket SRVSOCK = new ServerSocket(444);
        //Waits both client and server to accept and we return 
        //a socket
        Socket SOCK = SRVSOCK.accept();
        //Once accepted 
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String message = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("I read: " + message + "from Client");

        if(message != null)
        {
            //Sending message back to client 
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(SOCK.getOutputStream());
            ps.println("Message Received");
            ps.println("Send from Server");
        }
    }
}
```

Client

```
public class SOK_1_CLIENT {

    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception
    {
        SOK_1_CLIENT client = new SOK_1_CLIENT();
        client.run();
    }

    private void run() throws Exception {
        Socket SOCK = new Socket("localhost",444);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(SOCK.getOutputStream());
        ps.println("Hello to Server from client");

        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);

        String message = br.readLine();

        System.out.println(message);

    }

}
```

It only outputs message received however I think its because I need to have a loop to keep checking for new messages however not sure as I have just started this looking into sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client class, you need to  iterate the bufferedReader .

instead of

```
 String message = br.readLine();

 System.out.println(message);
```

use this,

```
 String message ;
 while((message = br.readLine())!=null) {
     System.out.println(message);
 }
```

Comment: You don't need the initializer.